# Boost.Stacktrace is absent in Debian repositories

Tags: boost, debian, stretch

As far as I can tell, boost.stacktrace library is absent in debian stretch repos (https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/boost-defaults).

Also, querying `find /usr/include/boost -name stacktrace.hpp` after installing `libboost-all-dev` gives nothing.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, boost.stacktrace was introduced in 1.65, while debian stretch is still at 1.62. Nevermind...